# can class inherit struct in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, inheritance

I have the following code in c++:

```
typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
   float c;
} Data;

class DataInfo : public Data
{
   // some code here
};
```

my question is can class inherit struct in C++? how this happens?

Comment: the same things? how come?

Comment: except all elements in a class are private by default

Comment: @user2131316 The only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is that the members of a `class` is `private` by default whereas the members of a `struct` are `public` by default. Same thing goes for inherritance

Comment: @user2131316: history. To make C's `struct`s classes they are just treated the same except that everything in a `struct` is `public` by default while in a class everything is `private` by default.

Comment: then this means they are not the same

Comment: @user2131316 It's a tiny difference, and if you state access modifier explicitly, it's totally insignificant.

Comment: @user2131316 They are. Both the `class` and `struct` keywords are used to declare and define **classes**. The definitions look different, but the entities they define behave in indistiguishable manner.

Comment: @user2131316 they are essentially the same. You can write exactly the same types using either. You can forward declare something as a `struct` and then define it as a `class`. Or vice versa.

Comment: Please don't use the nasty `typedef struct {} Name` construct.  It's ugly and unnecesarry!

Comment: @JohnDibling, I do not understand why it is unnecessary

Comment: It's unnecesarry because it gets you exactly *nothing*.  Just do `struct Name {};` instead.

Answer (score 9):

`struct` is included in C++ to provide complitability with C. It has same functionality as `class`, but members in struct are `public` by default. So you can inherit `class` from `struct` and do the same in reverse.